# VBA Selenium find row number by text

Tags: vba, selenium

I use the following code to locate the table row containing the text.

```
TabName = (driver.findElementByXPath("//div[@id='instrument_quote_source']/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/span").Text)
```

The Result is FOREX.

If I try to detect the row by the name FOREX and it doesn't work. I try this with:

```
TabName = driver.findElementByXPath("//div[@id='instrument_quote_source']/div/div/table/tbody/tr[td[contains(text(),'FOREX')]]/td[1]/span").Text
```

How can we identify the same place in the table by using only the name. Thanks.
I  tried already many combinations :(

Here is the macro:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim PageTimeoutms As Long
  Dim ProcessOk As Boolean
  Dim TabName As String

  PageTimeoutms = 20000
  driver.Start "firefox", "http://www.godmode-trader.de/rohstoffe/gold-preis,133979"
  driver.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 3000
  driver.Timeouts.Server = PageTimeoutms
  ProcessOk = driver.get("http://www.godmode-trader.de/rohstoffe/gold-preis,133979", PageTimeoutms)
  driver.findElementByLinkText("alle Börsenplätze anzeigen", PageTimeoutms).Click

  'TabName = (driver.findElementByXPath("//div[@id='instrument_quote_source']/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/span").Text)
  TabName = driver.findElementByXPath("//div[@id='instrument_quote_source']/div/div/table/tbody/tr[td[contains(text(),'FOREX')]]/td[1]/span").Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the cells form the targeted row:

```
Private Assert As New Assert

Sub Script1()
    Dim driver As New FirefoxDriver
    driver.Get "http://www.godmode-trader.de/rohstoffe/gold-preis,133979"
    driver.FindElementByLinkText("alle Börsenplätze anzeigen").Click

    Set row_forex = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[@id='instrument_quote_source']//tr[contains(.,'FOREX')]/td")
    Debug.Print row_forex(1).Text  ' > FOREX
    Debug.Print row_forex(2).Text  ' > $/Unze
    Debug.Print row_forex(3).Text  ' > 1.103,64
    driver.Quit
End Sub
```

Another solution would be to return all the values and then work with the desired row:

```
Sub Script2()
    Dim driver As New FirefoxDriver
    driver.Get "http://www.godmode-trader.de/rohstoffe/gold-preis,133979"
    driver.FindElementByLinkText("alle Börsenplätze anzeigen").Click

    Dim values()
    values = driver.FindElementByCss("#instrument_quote_source table").AsTable.Data()
    For r = 1 To UBound(values)
      If values(r, 1) Like "FOREX" Then
        Debug.Print values(r, 1)  ' > FOREX
        Debug.Print values(r, 2)  ' > $/Unze
        Debug.Print values(r, 3)  ' > 1.103,64
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
    driver.Quit
End Sub
```